# Merging two polygon layers with one layer having priority over other using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, merge, scale

How do I merge two polygon layers?

One is coarse scale over a large area (land use). The other is fine scale but is patchy (agricultural fields) in extent. I want the same extent of the land use layer and have the information of the land use layer but to replace with the fine detail of the agricultural fields where they occur. I am using ArcGIS 10.2.

Comment: Can you post some images showing examples of the data? That would make it easier to understand what is being asked.

Comment: I suggest that you try running an overlay and see if that produces what you need.  You could do a union if you have the Basic version; a union, identity or update if you have the advanced.  The union keeps the extent and all the attibutes of both layers, the identity keeps the extent and attributes of the coarse layer and adds in the information from the fields, the update replaces the coarse information with the fields where they overlap.

Comment: What about Union ? So you want one layer that has coarse and other fine layer in one layer ?

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. The union worked (I don't know why I didn't try that yesterday - I was stuck in a 'merging' rut).So the next question is now that I have a combined layer, how do I copy fields over. I have been trying in the field calculator to fill the blank cells from one field with the value (both are strings) from another field.  I have tried numerous versions, made sure I hit string type but have got "0's or an error.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. The union worked (I don't know why I didn't try that yesterday - I was stuck in a 'merging' rut).So the next question is now that I have a combined layer, how do I copy fields over. I have been trying in the field calculator to fill the blank cells from one field with the value (both are strings) from another field.  I have tried numerous versions, made sure I hit string type but have got "0's or an error. e.g  I selected the cells I wanted to change ('')......If [FIELD1] = '' then [FIELD2} else [FIELD1] but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I did work out a solution using **geodatabases** (as I had long field names in one layer). First I used a clip boundary of my study area and **erased** the areas with the fine data. I then ran an **intersect** on the two data layers and then a **spatial join**, choosing '**have their centre in**' as the match option. I then ran a **merge** to ensure I have all the attribute data in one layer. I then created a **new field** and copied the fine-scale data over to the new field. I then selected the rows where it **"ISNULL"** in the new field and used the **field calculator** to change them to the value of the coarse scale data (if that makes sense). Presto, I had one layer with both the fine-scale and coarse-scale data combined in one field.